# Помогите (объясните)

Tags: python

Нужно решить задачу:
Даны 3 числа. Определить отношение меньшего из них к большему.

(написать на python)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
max_number, min_number = max(a, b, c), min(a, b, c)
result = min_number / max_number
```

В переменной `result` будет нужное вам отношение.